# Maven including old versions of dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Maven to build a WAR file with the following parameters: mvn clean package

This builds successfully but when I open up the WAR I see the following:

```
jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
jackson-core-2.3.0.jar
pushy-0.2.jar
pushy-0.3.jar
```

This causes problems on our application server (Most likely conflicts), I proved this by manually deleting the old dependencies in the WAR which fixes any issues.

I have checked the Dependency Hierarchy view in Eclipse and I don't see versions 2.2.3 of Jackson or 0.2 of Pushy listed anywhere.

I have also tried deleting my whole .m2 repository but this doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Is there any particular reason why Maven would be including these old JARs?

Pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>core</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.threewks.thundr</groupId>
            <artifactId>thundr-mailgun</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Core.jar pom.xml depdencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.facebook4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[2.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relayrides</groupId>
            <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.threewks.thundr</groupId>
            <artifactId>thundr-mailgun</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the result of running the dependency tree parameter with mvn when building the WAR:

```
  [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ vimbaserver ---
[INFO] vimbaserver:vimbaserver:war:1.0
[INFO] +- core:core:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:platform:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.facebook4j:facebook4j-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.relayrides:pushy:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.11)
[INFO] |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (com.threewks.thundr:thundr-mailgun:jar:1.1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.31:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- com.threewks.thundr:thundr-mailgun:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.threewks.thundr:thundr-http:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.threewks.thundr:thundr:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.atomicleopard:expressive:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.jodd:jodd-bean:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.jodd:jodd-core:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.jodd:jodd-proxetta:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.6)
[INFO] |        |  \- (org.jodd:jodd-core:jar:3.4.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        +- org.jodd:jodd-servlet:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- (org.jodd:jodd-bean:jar:3.4.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        |  +- (org.jodd:jodd-core:jar:3.4.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        |  \- org.jodd:jodd-upload:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- (org.jodd:jodd-core:jar:3.4.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |           \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5)
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO]    \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

Comment: Show your full pom file.

Comment: Try using `mvn dependency:tree` to see from where the old version comes from.

Comment: Never use version ranges. Furthermore dependencies like mockito should have `<scope>test</scope>

Comment: I tried changing the scope to provided for Jackson and whats strange is that when I re-built the WAR it actually got rid of the duplicate dependencies (Which is good). Except that it excluded the new ones 2.3.0 as opposed to 2.2.3.

Comment: @infinite217 this is not your full pom, go to eclipse and click on the tab effective pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this before - please check your WEB-INF/ folder in the jboss directory for old jars.

Comment: Ahhh, just took a look at my WEB-INF/lib folder and I can see that I have the old artifacts in here. Presumably because in the past I had to put these in here in order for my application server to see them.

I just removed them and re-built my JAR and it looks like its working as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: @Infinite217 This is weird, you've said that your war contains the libs, I was about to say the same thing but stopped because of it. Try to be more clear in your future question. Anyway, solved problem is solved, that's all that matters :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see where is a dependency transitively included. Exclude them and use [Maven Enforcer](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) plugin to prevent a developer adding a dependency which adds banned transitive dependencies.

Comment: I ran mvn dependency:tree to see if there is a transitive dependency included but in the output there was no pushy 0.2 or jackson 2.2.3 listed. Any other ideas with regards to where these might be coming from when I build my WAR file?

Comment: Do the check again with verbose flag set(-Dverbose), maybe you get something.

Comment: Just re-ran the command with the verbose switch. Still no sign of the old artifact versions. Looking in my .m2 directory I don't even see these in my local repository.

Comment: Then it's not maven that is putting the jars to your war file.